# Why is the function I made giving me a None type?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column that shows the number of minutes a person has been on a certain site in a day and a second column that shows the number of minutes that a person uses the internet in a day.

My goal is to create a function that shows the ratio between the daily minutes on a site and the daily minutes that a person has used the Internet.

```
def percapitausage(x):

    x[0]/x[1]


df['Site/Internet Ratio']=df[['Daily Time Spent on Site','Daily Internet Usage']].apply(percapitausage,axis=1)
```

However, when I apply this function to my dataframe, the new column I created, 'Site/Internet Ratio', is filled with None values.

[image]

How can I fill my new column with the ratios that I want? Also, what mistake did I make in my code?

Comment: `def percapitausage(x): return x[0]/x[1]`. you forgot the **`return`** statement.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. What you have now is a syntax error, not a function.

Comment: Also, strive to do vectorized operations. Any time you do `apply`, it's code smell, especially for something so simple.

Comment: you have to use `return` in `def`. Or create lambda function which automatically returns last value - `percapitausage = lambda x: x[0]/x[1]`. Or you can use it directly in `.apply(lambda x:  x[0]/x[1], axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is giving you `None` because you are not returning anything. You can fix it by returning the value of `x[0]/x[1]`.

**Fixed Code**

```
def percapitausage(x):

    return x[0]/x[1]


df['Site/Internet Ratio']=df[['Daily Time Spent on Site','Daily Internet Usage']].apply(percapitausage,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your function to

```
def percapitausage(x):

    return x.iloc[0]/x.iloc[1]


df[['Daily Time Spent on Site','Daily Internet Usage']].apply(percapitausage,1)
```